# Java Web Programing

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I made a login page and process login info to a database. The class is to check for user and return his ID. Everything is going good until I pass the point where I initialize the variable UID. After that I have an SQL query which breaks the program. What is my mistake?
error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
```

login.jsp

```
</head>
<body>
    <%
    if(request.getParameter("submit")!=null)
    {
        String ime = request.getParameter("name");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        int uid = DbBroker.checkUser(name,pass);

        if (uid>0)
        {
            session.setAttribute("uid", name);
            response.sendRedirect("prodaja.jsp");
        }
        else if (uid==0)
        {
            session.setAttribute("uid", ime);
            response.sendRedirect("administrator.jsp");
        }       
        else  out.print("Korisnik nepostoji");

    }
    %>

</body>
```

dbBroker.java

```
public class DbBroker {

    public static Connection conn;

    public  static void conn()
    {
        try
        {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prodavnica", "root", "");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private void close()
    {
        try
        {
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }  

    public static int checkUser(String name, String pass) throws SQLException
    {
        conn();
        name=name.trim().replace("'", "");
        pass=pass.trim().replace("'","");
        int uid = -1;
        Statement st=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT id from user WHERE name='"+name+
                                     "' and pass='"+pass+"';");
        if (rs.next())
        {
            uid=rs.getInt("id");
        }
        conn.close();
        return uid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide the error as well, thnx.

Comment: Please show what you're sending as a name and pass as well. Also, what does conn() do?

Comment: And also, while your're at it, friggin' _hash your passwords_.

Comment: For that matter, if you don't want ' in your passwords, your UI should prevent the user from entering '. You shouldn't take the users password then remove characters out of it...they aren't going to know what it was.

Comment: Not sure, but you should be using [the SQL taglib](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html‎) to get information out of your databae into your UI instead of getting it from Java. At the minimum, a [prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) will be more secure.

Comment: error is 500 java.lang.NullPointerException, part of login.jsp code which is sending data to databese.class is    <%
        if(request.getParameter("submit")!=null)
        {
        String ime = request.getParameter("name");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        int uid = DbBroker.provera(name,pass);  and conn() is only conection to database

Comment: Check that name isn't null before doing name.trim(). Same for pass.

Comment: And change `while(rs.next())` to `if(rs.next())`: Surely your db isn't so poorly constructed as to have multiple rows with the same username and password.

Comment: Please include information like the exception in the body of the question, formatted (indented) as code, and include it from the start.  "It doesn't work" is one of the more infuriating statements in a question when it is not backed up with details of what goes wrong, with error messages if they're available.

Comment: Okey, no offense. But here is multiple things happening with this code which simply can't be fixed with larger re-factoring. Probably the biggest mistake with JSP you can make is to mix too much Java logic to your template. So instead of using those checks at template and checkUser(), you should have doPost() method at java side which processes sign in credentials given by the form, sets session attributes accordingly and redirects to different pages. You need to read book about JSP or find tutorials from the internet.

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code I don't know where to start. I don't want to answer where the NullPointerException is coming from and leave you to use the rest of the code as it is. Do some research on [password hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) as @Carsten suggests. Learn how to avoid SQL injection by using prepared statements... you should not have to remove single-quotes from usernames and passwords.

Comment: Or if your server supports it setup JAAS authentication realms as this is sooooo much easier.

Comment: tnx to all for answers and sugesttion , I am quite new in this

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add your "DbBroker" class in to JSP Page like:

**<%@ page import="packagename.DbBroker" %>**

```
<html>
<%@ page import="packagename.DbBroker" %>
   <head>
   </head>
<body>
    <%
    if(request.getParameter("submit")!=null)
    {
        String ime = request.getParameter("name");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        int uid = DbBroker.checkUser(name,pass);

        if (uid>0)
        {
            session.setAttribute("uid", name);
            response.sendRedirect("prodaja.jsp");
        }
        else if (uid==0)
        {
            session.setAttribute("uid", ime);
            response.sendRedirect("administrator.jsp");
        }       
        else  out.print("Korisnik nepostoji");

    }
    %>

</body>
</html>
```